# Write apostrophe sign in writeln function - Pascal

Tags: pascal

How can I print the apostrophe sign in Pascal using the `writeln` function?

Example:

```
writeln('My brother's book');
```

wouldn't work because `s book` is out of "writing" function, so the compiler returns an error:

```
Fatal: Syntax error, ")" expected but "identifier S" found
Fatal: Compilation aborted
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [the Free Pascal Reference](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse8.html): The single quote character can be embedded in the string by typing it twice:

```
writeln('By brother''s book');
```

Answer (score 0):

In Dev-Pascal 1.9.2 you will need three `'''`, for example:

```
writeln ('My brother'''s book');
```