# Pascal if then else doesn't work

Tags: if-statement, pascal, freepascal

I've got a problem with pascal. I'm learning it at school and because I already use Java, I'm a little bit confused. But that is not exactly why it doesn't work. I am trying to make a simple if (condition) write(this) else write(that) program, that runs in the cmd.
When I try to compile the following code, it says, I have to write a `;` instead of `else`, but that just seems odd.

```
program Project1;
var max : integer;
var max2 : integer;

begin
    writeln('Max: Oh no, I'm an integer');
    writeln('Which integer is max supposed to be?');
    readln (max);
    writeln('Max: I don't want to be a', max);
    writeln('Multiply Max');
    readln (max2);

    if (max = max * max2) then
        writeln('NO, I do not want to be a', max);
    else
        writeln('I think I could live with being a ', max * max2);

    readln;
end.
```

Comment: Double the apostrophe, the doubling acts as escape: Writeln('I don''t want to be a ',max);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
program Project1;
var max : integer;
var max2 : integer;
begin
writeln('Max: Oh no, Im an integer');
writeln('Which integer is max supposed to be?');
readln (max);
writeln('Max: I dont want to be a', max);
writeln('Multiply Max');
readln (max2);
if (max = max * max2) then
 writeln('NO, I do not want to be a', max)
 else
  writeln('I think I could live with being a ', max * max2);

readln;
end.
```

Problem was with if statement, because if is just one line you don't need to close line with ";"  and was problems with string lines, don't use " ' " in middle of string

Comment: Problem was with string lines because with ' you closet it too early, and if statment if is with one line you dont't need use ; before else

Comment: You should [edit] to explain the fix you've provided, rather than posting simply code changes. If you don't explain why the code needs to be changed, you're not providing any knowledge here.

Answer (score 2):

Try fixing your apostrophes in the writelns, and see if that helps:

[Write apostrophe sign in writeln function - Pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174313/write-apostrophe-sign-in-writeln-function-pascal)

Comment: I don't really see, where I used and apostrophe in a writeln. The ones that are in them are to end displaying text. (I want it to print the value of max)

Comment: writeln('Max: Oh no, I'm an integer');
writeln('Max: I don't want to be a', max);

Comment: you can see, why I did that in my edited reply... (forgot to write it there)